# '.cssclass input[type=checkbox]:checked + label' replacement for CheckBoxFor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to apply custom CSS styling to a front end HTML element that is generated from the model (we use C# ASP.NET MVC style).

Here is the current code to generate the checkbox in the view:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.elementCollection[i].booleanValue)%>
```

The CSS method in an example I am using as my resource contains the following:

```
.checkboxThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
left: 60px;
background: #26ca28;
}
```

How can I make the CSS trigger on all checkbox elements generated from the model instead of on all HTML inputs of type checkbox?

Comment: Can you add a class to the generated checkbox elements, and then select that class in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
.checkboxThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
```

to

```
.checkboxThree input[type="checkbox"]:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label:after {
```

MVC adds the hidden one in the middle, and this CSS requires you to have the first and last in a row

Comment: What is the significance of '+' between checked and label? Plz tell.

Comment: the + sign tells css to only look for instances where the elements are after eachother. if you put something in between, it is not in a row anymore, and css will ignore that.